# Wicd cannot detect wireless networks

Tags: linux, wicd

Wicd cannot detect wireless networks, but it works well with wired network.

I just learn to install this kind of linux OS, so I got no idea for any configuration.

Comment: what Linux OS is it?

Comment: @bfhd! Sorry for late reply to you. It was Point Linux OS. No problem now, because I installed Ubuntu instead, and everything works well without any configuration of wireless network. Thanks any way!